# "No valid system or dataset was specified" while using predict() in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, svm, cross-validation, predict

I am trying to classify my input features into two classes using SVM. I want to use 10-fold cross-validation to train an SVM classifier. I am using MATLAB inbuilt functions. But while using `predict()` function along with `crossval()` function, I am getting an error:

> No valid system or dataset was specified.

Does anyone knows how to resolve this issue?

```
Training_Features   = X;
Training_Labels     = Y;
SVMModel           = 
fitcsvm(Training_Features,Training_Labels,'KernelFunction','RBF');       
CVSVMModel          = crossval(SVMModel);

[Predict_Labels,Predict_Scores]     = 
predict(CVSVMModel,Training_Features);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you understood the cross validation functionality wrong. Your `CVSVMModel` is a so called `ClassificationPartitionedModel` which has no function `predict()` since Cross Validation is meant for testing the generalisation of your model BEFORE you train it with the WHOLE dataset (not cross-validated).

I suggest the following:

1. Call `[Predict_Labels,Predict_Scores] = kfoldPredict(CVSVMModel);` to see how well it does on each validation dataset during the cross-validation
2. If you're satisfied train a new `SVMModel` with the whole dataset and predict with that one.

EDIT:
A `ClassificationPartitionedModel` is a collection of models (in your case 10 different ones). You can access and even call `predict()` on them by for example:

```matlab
[Predict_Labels,Predict_Scores] = predict(CVSVMModel.Trained{1, 1},X);
```